# IOS14 didWriteValueFor characteristics.value always return null. (iOS 12 OK)

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

for CoreBluetooth, I am sending a write to a characteristic in order to set a Wattage Target (cycling trainer app) which is of characteristicType `.writeResponse`

When the target power is sent, the trainer does accept the data, and then the code will trigger the `didWriteValueFor` function call.
However the resultant data that gets printed out is different between iOS12 and iOS14.

Somehow for iOS14, no data gets returned so I won't know if the command actually worked.(which isn't a problem when I have a physical device which I can test on, but is a big problem when trying to debug what's wrong w/ a user over the other side of the world).

Anyone has any idea how to get the value to be `non-null`?

```
iOS14
  >>>>>>>> sendTargetPower charTacxFECWrite
         -- targetPower     : 0.0 data:{length = 13, bytes = 0xa4094f0531ffffffffff0000ff}
         -- txCharacteristic: Optional(<CBCharacteristic: 0x2823f0420, UUID = 6E40FEC3-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E, properties = 0xC, value = (null), notifying = NO>)
         -- peripheral      : Optional(<CBPeripheral: 0x2836d5400, identifier = A3740C60-AD97-D34B-0096-8C4DE5C211BE, name = 58905-5, mtu = 23, state = connected>)

  =-=-=-=- didWriteValueFor 
  =-=-=-=-=-= Peripheral: <CBPeripheral: 0x2836d5400, identifier = A3740C60-AD97-D34B-0096-8C4DE5C211BE, name = 58905-5, mtu = 23, state = connected>
  =-=-=-=-=-= char      : <CBCharacteristic: 0x2823f0420, UUID = 6E40FEC3-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E, properties = 0xC, value = (null), notifying = NO>
  =-=-=-=-=-= char.value: nil
  =-=-=-=-=-= Error     : nil

  =-=-=-=- didUpdateValueFor TACX FEC Write
  =-=-=-=-=-= Peripheral: <CBPeripheral: 0x2836d5400, identifier = A3740C60-AD97-D34B-0096-8C4DE5C211BE, name = 58905-5, mtu = 23, state = connected>
  =-=-=-=-=-= char      : <CBCharacteristic: 0x2823f0420, UUID = 6E40FEC3-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E, properties = 0xC, value = (null), notifying = NO>
  =-=-=-=-=-= char.value: nil
```

for iOS12, this is what comes out:

```
  =-=-=-=- didWriteValueFor 
  =-=-=-=-=-= Peripheral: <CBPeripheral: 0x2812241e0, identifier = E782746D-BFC3-E4FA-8E52-3106D8FE4AA8, name = 58905-5, state = connected>
  =-=-=-=-=-= char      : <CBCharacteristic: 0x28072fcc0, UUID = 6E40FEC3-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E, properties = 0xC, value = (null), notifying = NO>
  =-=-=-=-=-= char.value: nil
  =-=-=-=-=-= Error     : nil

  =-=-=-=- didUpdateValueFor TACX FEC Write
  =-=-=-=-=-= Peripheral: <CBPeripheral: 0x2812241e0, identifier = E782746D-BFC3-E4FA-8E52-3106D8FE4AA8, name = 58905-5, state = connected>
  =-=-=-=-=-= char      : <CBCharacteristic: 0x28072fcc0, UUID = 6E40FEC3-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E, properties = 0xC, value = <a4094f05 31ffffff ffff0000 ff>, notifying = NO>
  =-=-=-=-=-= char.value: Optional(13 bytes)
```

These are the code which triggers the print outs.

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
  for characteristic in service.characteristics! as [CBCharacteristic] {
    switch characteristic.uuid {
    case charTacxFECNotify:
      peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
      
    case charTacxFECWrite:
      peripheral.writeValue(data, for: characteristics, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
        CSVfuncs.writeLog("  >>>>>>>> sendTargetPower charTacxFECWrite START")
        CSVfuncs.writeLog("           -- targetPower     : \(targetPower) data:\(NSData.init(data: data))")
        CSVfuncs.writeLog("           -- txCharacteristic: \(String(describing: txCharacteristic))")
        CSVfuncs.writeLog("           -- peripheral      : \(String(describing: tacxFecPeripheral))")
        CSVfuncs.writeLog("  >>>>>>>> sendTargetPower charTacxFECWrite END")
    }
  }
```

... more code...

```
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52147630/corebluetooth-didwritevaluefor-is-not-called-after-writevalue
  // this gets called whenever a write occurs (w/ a .withResponse write type)
  func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    // Added this per SO[1] for testing
    // When enabled, it will call didUpdateValueFor (resulting in the printout titled "didUpdateValueFor TACX FEC Write"
    peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic) 
    CSVfuncs.writeLog("  =-=-=-=- didWriteValueFor ")
    CSVfuncs.writeLog("  =-=-=-=-=-= Peripheral: \(peripheral)")
    CSVfuncs.writeLog("  =-=-=-=-=-= char      : \(characteristic)")
    CSVfuncs.writeLog("  =-=-=-=-=-= char.value: \(characteristic.value)")
    CSVfuncs.writeLog("  =-=-=-=-=-= Error     : \(error)\n")
}

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    switch characteristic.uuid {
    case charTacxFECWrite:  // This is WRITE, will only get called IF we put a readValue after sending a write
      CSVfuncs.writeLog("  =-=-=-=- didUpdateValueFor TACX FEC Write")
      CSVfuncs.writeLog("  =-=-=-=-=-= Peripheral: \(peripheral)")
      CSVfuncs.writeLog("  =-=-=-=-=-= char      : \(characteristic)")
      CSVfuncs.writeLog("  =-=-=-=-=-= char.value: \(characteristic.value)\n")
}
```

Referenced SO which I tried to resolve this issue. (to no avail)

1. [CoreBluetooth: didWriteValueFor() is not called after writeValue()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52147630/14414215)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41219858/14414215
3. [Receive the response sent by bluetooth control point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64656756/14414215)

Comment: You haven't got notification enabled for the characteristic, so how is `didUpdateValue` being called? Are you initiating a read after the write?

Comment: @Paulw11 so glad you are helping. Anyhow, the printouts are automatically based on the code's process flow. Hence the ```didWriteValueFor``` and ```didUpdateValueFor```  output are as printed. I have also tried initiating a ```readValue()``` [within ```didWriteValueFor```] as well as putting a ```peripheral.setNotifyValue``` within ```didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor``` (although in the above codes you can see that I've commented them out, but I did try them both commented and uncommented to the same effect.)

Comment: `didUpdateValueFor` should not be called unless 1) you issue a `read` or 2) you have enabled notifications.  You don't seem to have done either of these things, so I am a bit confused as to why this method is being called at all.

Comment: I've searched the code for occurrences of ```setNotify``` or ```readValue``` and updated the original question. The ```didUpdateValueFor``` is triggered from the ```readValue```  within ```didWriteValueFor``` (I added the comment in the Original Post). When this (the read within ```didwriteValue``` ) is commented out, then ```didUpdateValueFor is not called and I won't see the print statements. However, the ```characteristic.value``` is still NULL (iOS14). iOS12 seems to work tho.

Comment: Looking at the properties of the characteristic you are reading, it has value 0x0c which is 0x04 and 0x08 - This is write and write without notify.  It doesn't have 0x02 - The read property, so it isn't legal to read this characteristic.  - Can you show your `didUpdate` code?

Comment: Updated what the ```didUpdate``` code. Essentially nothing there except to print out those messages. On a tester's debugLog output sent to me, his trainer sent a ```properties = 0x28``` which is a 0x20 (Indicate) and 0x08 (write w/o notify). I'm not too sure what ```indicate``` does but I think from the desc it's basically ```notify``` with reponse. which means can't read it as well? if it's not legal, does that mean that could be the reason why iOS12 has data and iOS14 doesn't? (apple fixed it?)

Comment: This post also see something similar. iOS12 is OK, iOS13 is not https://stackoverflow.com/q/58059834/1441421

Comment: Normally you would use indicate/notify rather than reading the value.  It is more efficient than polling.  It is odd that you aren't seeing the `indicate` property

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235003/discussion-between-myjunk-and-paulw11).

Comment: @app4g Did you manage to resolve it? I am also always getting the value as null for the characterisitic. Any help is appreciated

Comment: @Sudhanshu nope.. this was never resolved. I'm still running my app on IOS12 and it works.

Comment: @Sudhanshu by chance, are you setting ```setNotify``` on that characteristic?

Comment: @app4g Yes I am setting SetNotify on that characteristic. Because it has the property Notify and Indicate